How to free chars* in a char**
I don't understand how to free() the strings in my array char**
When I try to do it in this code I got a segfault and 40 bytes lost with valgrind
int     main(void)
{
    char    **strs;
    char    *ret;
    char    *sep = "...";
    int     size = 4;
    int     i = 0;

    strs = malloc(sizeof(char *) * 4);
    while (i < 4)
    {
        strs[i] = malloc(sizeof(char) * 10);
        i++;
    }
    strs[0] = "Why";
    strs[1] = "it";
    strs[2] = "doesn't";
    strs[3] = "work";

    ret = foofoo(size, strs, sep);
    printf("%s\n", ret);

    i = 0;
    while (i < size)
    {
        free(strs[i]);
        i++;
    }
    free(strs);
    free(ret);
    
    return (0);
}

If I remove this part, no error will occur but if I compile with gcc -g and execute with valgrind I definitely lost 40 bytes because i don't free() the strings.
    while (i < size)
    {
        free(strs[i]);
        i++;
    }

Can you explain me please.
Thx

Every malloc should be matched with a free. strs[i] = malloc(sizeof(char) * 10); matches free(strs[i]); The problem you have is you've overwritten those pointers with values not allocated with malloc like strs[0] = "Why"; and so you can no longer free the memory. It is leaked since you have no pointer to it.

@RetiredNinja Any reason not to make that an answer?

@RetiredNinja Yeah you right I understand now, but so how I can add 'chars' in these strings without lost the adress given by malloc for each strings ?

@Yunnosch Feel free if you like. I'm sure there's a dupe out there but haven't been able to find the right one.

@Plaket strcpy would be one way to copy data into the allocated space.

strs[0] = "Why"; should be strcpy(strs[0], "Why"); and so on.
